# How to target one widget on my Wordpress homepage without effecting other sections?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having trouble changing the styles of a widget on my Wordpress site.

The one I am targeting is the bottommost one on the homepage: http://rfm-inc.com. It is the section of the page that reads "Proud member of the Mitsubishi Materials family of companies"."

The styles seem to be mainly applied to the ID ".content", but I'd like to alter those styles ONLY at the ".text-3" level.

I can change the content stylings and get the effect I want in the widget, but it changes all of the other widgets.

I want the bottom widget to fully span the page (ie, full blue background, centered text, resizing and wrapping text at smaller screen widths), but to leave the other sections alone.

Any tips on how to target this widget independent of the other sections?

Comment: Better to ask this question on this site, http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll do that for sure, once I finish this question.

Comment: I posted this over on wordpress.stackexchange.com and they told me that this is a "general CSS and HTML question" that I should ask over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually wordpress widgets have a their own style css file in wp-content/plugin and the name of the plugin.
Anyway if you open the developer tools on the web browser and you click on the element you want to change, you will figure out which selector to use.
Make some test on the developer tool and then make the changes on your files.

Comment: That's what I've been doing, and, like I said, I have been able to target that widget, but there are things about the .content ID that seem to be applied no matter what I do...

Answer (score 0):

In this EXACT CASE you can do it with:

```
.widget:last-child {
    /* your rules */
}
```

As this is the last child of the **section id="main"**.

Or use its ID:

```
#text-3 {
    /* your rules */
}
```

Comment: So I've been playing a bit with this, and I have to different scenarios live right now:

Comment: Oops. Try again. Two scenarios: 1) the slider (ul.slides) at width: 123.4% and 2) the banner (#text-3) at 100%. The banner resizes properly, but it doesn't cover the full width of the page. The slider doesn't resize properly, as when I go to a narrower screen, some of it is displaying outside of the page width. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Haven't heard anything on this. Any other ideas? Or ideas about how I could ask this question differently to get some more ideas?

Comment: The banner resizes properly, and it covers the width it is allowed to cover - your #content has a media query and a rule to add 2em margin. #text-3 is inside #content, so its 100% width is bounded by the margin of its ancestor. You could give #text-3 a position:absolute; left:0;width:100% - but then you would need to update other elements too. (If you want it to be full-width, of course. :) )

Comment: Thanks @muka.gergely—see my answer. I figured it out.

Comment: Nicely done :) Happy that I could shed some light on the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I solved it. Let's see if I can explain.

First, I changed the #content container to:

```css
body.home #content.col-full {
    max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

This of course expanded the full container.

Then I was able to style individual widgets as needed.

It was the more parent element that needed styling, then everything else flowed from there. But it was hard for me to target, since I:

1. Didn't know how to target only the home page (body.home)
2. Didn't see that the container was #content
3. Didn't realize that the easiest thing to do was to adjust the container and to style the contained widgets separately